# Recursividad y números perfectos en c++

Tags: c++

Hice un programa para hallar si un numero es perfecto usando recursividad. El problema es que mi programa solo aguanta hasta 4000 aproximadamente.
Pasado de eso aparece este mensaje:

> Excepción no controlada en 0x00007FF76A1C27BE en ConsoleApplication1.exe: 0xC00000FD: Stack overflow (parámetros: 0x0000000000000001, 0x00000003EA083FF0).

Ayuda porfa

```cpp
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int perfecto(int n, int a)
{
   if (a <= 1)
   {
      return 1;
   }
   else
   {
      int b;
      if ((n % a) == 0)
      {
         b = a;
      }
      else
      {
         b = 0;
      }
      return (b + perfecto(n, a - 1));
   }
}

int main()
{
   int numero;
   cout << "ingrese un numero entero positivo: ";
   cin >> numero;
   if (perfecto(numero, numero - 1) == numero)
   {
      cout << "el numero es perfecto";
   }
   else
   {
      cout << "el numero no es perfecto";
   }
}
```

Comment: Es el problema que hay con la recursividad... El mensaje de `stack overflow` (además de ser un foro maravilloso) indica que ha habido un desborde en la memoria. Normalmente estos errores se dan cuando el algoritmo que empleas en la recursividad no está bien pensado. Dale una vuelta a cómo lo estás programando, que tenga métodos de salida, etc. Porque lo que te está ocurriendo es que para algunos números se quedará pillado dentro de la función continuamente, llamándose toooodo el rato, y eso hace que la memoria se llene y quiera acceder a memoria restringida.

Answer (score 1):

Cada vez que se llama a una función, debe reservarse memoria para las variables de esa función y para que la función tenga un espacio para "*ejecutar cosas*", esto tiene un coste en tiempo de proceso y en memoria. Normalmente este coste es insignificante, pero usando recursividad este coste aumenta en cada nivel de recursión.

Posiblemente cuando llegas cerca de 4000<sup>1</sup> se supera la cantidad que el sistema considera aceptable para la memoria que necesitan las funciones y te muestra el error.

Puedes intentar solucionar este problema de tres maneras:

#### [Optimización de la recursión de cola (*Tail recursion optimization*)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tail_call).

Escribiendo tu recursión de cierta manera, el compilador puede transformar la recursión en una sola función. Si tu código ya está redactado así y se está haciendo la recursión, intenta subir las opciones de optimización de tu compilador.

#### Abandonar la recursión.

Puedes dejar de usar recursión para este problema y pasar a una función con un bucle.

#### Aumentar el espacio del stack.

Los compiladores ofrecen opciones de compilación que aumentan el límite de profundidad en que una recursión puede fallar. No se qué compilador estás usando, pero si usas Visual Studio puedes configurar esto en:

- Project properties → Linker → System → Stack Reserve Size

Este valor está en bytes, así que si quieres 4Mb de tamaño de stack, deberás introducir 1024✕1024✕4=**4194304**. Pero esto sólo cambiará el problema de sitio, ya que si agotas los 4Mb volverás a tener el mismo problema.

---

1<sub>Apuesto que en 4096, que es una potencia de 2 (2<sup>12</sup>)</sub>